How to bound $\mu (\{ x \le X : |ψ(x) − x| \ge εx^{1/2} (\log x)^2 \})$ from above?
From the following estimate $$ \int_0^X |ψ(x) − x|^{2k} dx ≪ (ck^2)^k X^{k+1}   \tag{1}$$ where $c$ is an absolute constant, I want to prove the following estimate $$ µ ( \{ x \le X : |ψ(x) − x| \ge  εx^{1/2} (\log x)^2 \} )  ≪   X^{1−c′ε^{1/2}}     \tag{2}$$ where $c' = 2 \exp(−c/2 − 1) + o(1)$ and $o(1) → 0$ as $X → 0$.
My attempt: In Formula $(2)$, we name the set $A$. By definition of Lebesgue measure, $\mu(A) = \int_0^X 1_A (x) dx$ where $1_A (x)$ is an indicator function, i.e. it is $1$ when $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. One approach is to write $$1 \le \dfrac{ |ψ(x) − x|}{εx^{1/2} (\log x)^2} \implies \mu(A) = \int_0^X 1_A (x) dx \le \int_0^X  \dfrac{ |ψ(x) − x|}{εx^{1/2} (\log x)^2}$$ then use Formula $(1)$; but this is not correct since $1_A (x)$ is not identity function $1$. Also, in Formula $(1)$ integration is over all $x$ from $0$ to $X$ and it does not give any information about the set $A$. Even with a rough estimate (using dyadic decomposition for the integral) there is no progress I could make: $$\begin{align}1 &\le \dfrac{ |ψ(x) − x|}{εx^{1/2} (\log x)^2} \\\implies 1^{2k}&\le (\dfrac{ |ψ(x) − x|}{εx^{1/2} (\log x)^2})^{2k} \\\implies \mu(A)& = \int_0^X 1_A (x) dx\\&\le\left(\int_{0^+}^{2 \times 0^+} + \dots \int_{X/2}^X\right)  \left(\dfrac{ |ψ(x) − x|}{εx^{1/2} (\log x)^2}\right)^{2k} dx\end{align}$$ bringing out the dominator each time (considering for lower bound) and final estimate of sum doesn't result Formula $(2)$!
My question is how to prove $(2)$ considering $(1)$?
Added note after current bounty: I will reward 100 more bounty for the correct answer.

You should use {...}, not {}.

Use a dyadic decomposition for the integral.

@PeterHumphries that's what I did in OP but it doesn't lead in any result

Here's a different estimate that you can prove. Via a dyadic subdivision,
$$\mu\left(\left\{2 \leq x \leq X : |\psi(x) - x| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{x}(\log x)^2\right\}\right) \leq \sum_{\ell = 2}^{\left\lceil \frac{\log X}{\log 2} \right\rceil} \mu\left(\left\{2^{\ell - 1} \leq x \leq 2^{\ell} : |\psi(x) - x| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{x}(\log x)^2\right\}\right).$$
By Chebyshev's inequality, for any $k_{\ell} > 0$, each summand on the right-hand side is bounded by
$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{2k_{\ell}}} \int_{2^{\ell - 1}}^{2^{\ell}} \frac{|\psi(x) - x|^{2k_{\ell}}}{x^{k_{\ell}} (\log x)^{2k_{\ell}}} \, dx \leq \left(\frac{1}{2^{\ell - 1} (\ell - 1)^2 (\log 2)^2 \varepsilon^2}\right)^{k_{\ell}} \int_{2^{\ell - 1}}^{2^{\ell}} |\psi(x) - x|^{2k_{\ell}} \, dx.$$
By assumption, this is bounded by a constant multiple of
$$\left(\frac{2c k_{\ell}^2}{(\ell - 1)^2 (\log 2)^2 \varepsilon^2}\right)^{k_{\ell}} 2^{\ell}.$$
This is minimised by taking $k_{\ell} = \frac{(\ell - 1) (\log 2) \varepsilon}{\sqrt{2ce}}$, so that this is at most
$$2^{\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2ce}}} 2^{\ell\left(1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2ce}}\right)}.$$
So for $\varepsilon \leq \sqrt{2ce}$, we find that
$$\mu\left(\left\{2 \leq x \leq X : |\psi(x) - x| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{x}(\log x)^2\right\}\right) \ll 2^{\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2ce}}} \sum_{\ell = 2}^{\lceil \frac{\log X}{\log 2} \rceil} 2^{\ell\left(1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2ce}}\right)} \ll X^{1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2ce}}}.$$

(Thank you for your answer and my slow reply (depression) ..)

Why do you enter $(l-1)$ factor in the denominator in estimation of the integral?

$$x^{k_{\ell}} (\log x)^{2k_{\ell}} \geq (2^{\ell - 1})^{k_{\ell}} (\log (2^{\ell - 1}))^{2k_{\ell}} = (2^{\ell - 1} (\ell - 1)^2 (\log 2)^2)^{k_{\ell}}.$$

Sorry, in $(2)$ in the exponential it is $\epsilon^{1/2}$ and not $\epsilon$.

Also your new constant is not same as c' in (2)
